# Check_box tag is returning empty array locations when using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Earlier I was using a check_box_tag with form_tag with multiple checkboxes. This returned an array in the parameters something like ["student","teacher"]. I am just computing posts to be shown by the users who shared them by creating a function in the controller and using the parameters.The parameters look like

```
user_type=>["student","teacher"]
```

But now I am shifting to form_for tag because I am using a different model and I want the parameters in a proper format. The params passed now look like

```
filter_obj=>{user_type=>["","",""student,"teacher"]}
```

Here's my checkbox code

```
<% User::OPEN_USER_TYPES.each do |type|%>
<div class="radio-check-group <%='hide-group' if container == "my-contribution"  %>">
            <div class="control"><%= f.check_box(:user_type,{:multiple => true},type,nil)%></div>
            <div class="label"><%= f.label(:user_type,type,:value=>type)-%></div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Is there a way so that the form passes the parameters like filter_obj=>{user_type =>["student","teacher"]}. I don't want to do extra processing for cleaning the array in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the [method name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) following `:user_type`:

```
f.check_box(:user_type,[method_name],{:multiple => true},type,nil) #method name might be 'occupation'
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of a way to do so, using `check_box`. You can use `check_box_tag` instead of `check_box` but it is not as elegant, as it is for `check_box`

```
<% User::OPEN_USER_TYPES.each do |type|%>
    <div class="radio-check-group <%='hide-group' if container == "my-contribution"  %>">
        <div class="control">
           <%= check_box_tag "filter_obj[user_type][]", type, @filter_obj.user_type.to_a.include?(type) %>
        </div>
        <div class="label">
           <%= f.label(:user_type,type,:value=>type)-%>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @nightf0x..what is wrong with my answer..why did u unaccept it?